# Error while changing image of UIButton inside Tableview Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UIButton inside a TableView Cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

  UIButton *ImageViewFavorited = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:7];

        [ImageViewFavorited addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

I want to change the background image for this button on click event so I have an Action tied to this button :

```
- (IBAction)BtnClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"I enter in  BtnClicked");
    UIImage *ImageNNotFavorited = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NotFavorited"];

    [sender setImage:ImageNNotFavorited];
}
```

After running this code I have the following Error:

```
-[UIButton setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd19c83ea00
```

I don't know how to fix this, do you have an idea  ?

Comment: This will be much easier to resolve if you change your action to: `- (IBAction)BtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender {`. Also note that variable and method names should start with lowercase letters. Class names start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 4):

To set the image on a `UIButton`, you also need to specify what control state you want the image to be shown for. For example:

```
[sender setImage:ImageNNotFavorited forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```